# Rest android applications

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I apologize if my questions seems to be repetitive but I couldn't find a answer for this yet.

I would like to make calls GET, POST, PUT, DELETE on my application.
For calls using GET and POST I'm using http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

I would like PUT and DELETE calls.

I apologize if the question is simple, but do not know about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article you linked, only `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` are handled, but [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html) provides all of the REST actions - `HttpGet`, `HttpPost`, `HttpPut`, `HttpDelete`, all of which implement the `HttpRequest` interface.

If you wanted to use that same code, you'd want to add two additional case statements for PUT and DELETE, building the right request object and then executing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTTPPut](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPut.html) and [httpDelete](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpDelete.html).

They will follow the same usage pattern as HTTPGet from your tutorial.

Regards,
 Stéphane